# theme.res is not merged from svn in codenameone

Tags: forms, svn, codenameone

We(I and friend) are recently working on single project of codenameone. We both create forms in the theme and the newly added forms are displayed. But the problem is when new components are added in single form  then new components added my friend are not displayed in the form even I have updated the project which is committed by my friend in svn.

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are binary so you would get conflicts, you should commit the XML hierarchy under the res directory where you should be able to merge differences (although individual forms are still binary by default).

Comment: comment is done via res folder and conflicts are resolved and Main.ui is updated but it is not updated in UI (theme.res) , it shows own UI not updated UI.
Why and how to solve this ?